# PHP SQLSRV: passing a string of values to IN clause

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I need a way to perform the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE column NOT IN ('val1', 'val2')
```

Now, `val1` and `val2` are inside an array that I'm imploding into a string like this:

```
$inClause = "'" . implode("','", $inClauseArr) . "'";
```

If I put the string in the query declaration like this it works:

```
$sql = "[...]WHERE column NOT IN ($inClause)";
```

But if I pass it as a `sqlsrv_query` parameter like this, the query is not working:

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array($inClause));
```

I'm not getting any error. `$stmt` is true but `while` cycle is not returning anything.

I absolutely need to pass it through `sqlsrv_query`, how can i do this?

---

**UPDATE**

Here's the `$sql` value:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders(NOLOCK)
WHERE order_id NOT IN (?)
```

Comment: Can you show us the value of `$sql` when you attempt to use the parameters?

Comment: @ImClarky can't see how this can help, but I've updated the question (actually it's quite the same of the first code quote)

Comment: You should also populate question marks in your sql query according to `$inClauseArr` length.

Comment: @alalp it would look exactly like the first query i've posted...am I misunderstaing something in your requests?

Answer (score 1):

Count of question marks in your original SQL query must match with the count of parameters you have passed into the query.

Supposing `$inClauseArr` is like:

```
$inClauseArr = array('val1', 'val2');
```

There are two elements. Actually, it is not important how much element it has. As long as `$inClauseArr` is an array, there will be no problem.

So, the query should be constructed as (*[...]* is the beginning of the query):

```
$sql = "[...]WHERE column NOT IN ("
    . implode(',', array_fill(0, count($inClauseArr), '?'))
    . ")";

// For $inClauseArr = array('val1', 'val2');
// Output should be [...]WHERE column NOT IN (?, ?)
```

And execution should be like:

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $inClauseArr);
```

References:

- [`sqlsrv_query`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296184(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)
- [`array_fill`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php)

Comment: That's exactly what i'm doing now, but i need to avoid generating pieces of query in the code because the query will have to be stored in a db table. Then i'll need to retrieve it from there **AS STRING** and execute it just passing the values to the `sqlsrv_query`, without the need of manipulate it. It seems this method doesn't allow an easy way of using the SQL `IN` clause

Comment: @Mark I think you can parse comma separated `$inClause` string in your sql query to populate a dynamic table. Then you can use that table in `IN` clause (or maybe with `INNER JOIN`).

Answer (score 0):

Pass it in a a comma delimited string (varchar) then use a split function to create a table:

```
     declare @vars varchar(14) =  'G' + ',' + 'H'

     select * from syscode_detail 
     where code in (select value from dbo.Split(@vars, ','))

     using this function:

     CREATE function [dbo].[Split]
     (
      @List nvarchar(2000),
      @SplitOn nvarchar(5)
      )  

    returns @tblReturn table 
    (
    id int identity(1,1),
    value nvarchar(100)
    ) 
 as  
Begin

    While (Charindex(@SplitOn, @List) > 0)
    Begin
        Insert Into @tblReturn (value)
        Select value = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@List, 1, Charindex(@SplitOn,
        @List) - 1)))

        Set @List = Substring(@List, Charindex(@SplitOn, @List) + 
        len(@SplitOn), len(@List))
    End

    Insert Into @tblReturn (value)
    Select Value = ltrim(rtrim(@List))

    Return

End
```

Comment: Thanks @Gregg, to create or modify stored/functions is not allowed in this project...i would need a solution on the PHP side